# Reload workbook in SharePoint 2010 Excel Web Access

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010

I am developing a webpage for users to view some Excel workbooks in SharePoint webpage.
The workbook is a kind of report to users and will be updated by admin every week by overwrite the excel file in SharePoint.

I know we can reload the workbook manually by clicking File->Reload Workbook. However, if we take this appoarch, every user needs to click the button on their own which is not what we want!! So I would like to do this automatically.

Is there any method to solve this? Any advice is welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

This post my help you.The approach is adding a javascript code to XLViewer.aspx in order to immediately refresh the connections of the Excel Services viewer on every visit.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28190/how-to-reload-worksheet-displayed-in-excel-web-access-webpart

Comment: As I am new to SP2010, may I know where's the XLViewer.aspx? Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Templates\Layouts